# How to use onlyAddOneLineAlertMessage prop in Ant design pro Editable Pro Table to change the Alert message

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

Im using ant design pro editable pro tables. But i cannot change the alert message in onlyAddOneLineAlertMessage.

```
<EditableProTable
          rowKey="id"
          actionRef={actionRef}
          headerTitle=""
          //maxLength={5}
          recordCreatorProps={{ creatorButtonText: 'Add Recipents' }}
          columns={columns}
          request={async () => ({
            data: data,
            total: 3,
            success: true,
          })}
          value={csvArray}
          onChange={setCsvArray}
          onlyOneLineEditorAlertMessage={'dasdas'}
          onlyAddOneLineAlertMessage={'dasdas'}
          editable={{
            type: 'single',
            editableKeys,
            onSave: async (rowKey, data, row) => {
            },
            onChange: setEditableRowKeys,
            actionRender: (row, config, defaultDom) => [
              defaultDom.save,
              defaultDom.delete || defaultDom.cancel,
            ],
          }}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution for this. those two props should write inside the editable prop.

```
<EditableProTable
          rowKey="id"
          actionRef={actionRef}
          headerTitle=""
          recordCreatorProps={{ creatorButtonText: 'Add Recipents' }}
          columns={columns}
          request={async () => ({
            data: data,
            total: 3,
            success: true,
          })}
          value={csvArray}
          onChange={setCsvArray}
          editable={{
            type: 'single',
            editableKeys,
            onSave: async (rowKey, data, row) => {
            },
            onChange: setEditableRowKeys,
            actionRender: (row, config, defaultDom) => [
              defaultDom.save,
              defaultDom.delete || defaultDom.cancel,
            ],
            onlyOneLineEditorAlertMessage={'dasdas'}
            onlyAddOneLineAlertMessage={'dasdas'}
          }}
        />
```